# I want to fetch data from Mysql database through retrofit2 api

Tags: php, android, api, syntax-error, retrofit2

Actually I want to fetch data from Mysql database through retrofit2 api. I am fetching data on the basis of some category like category 1 or 2 but I am getting error `@Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)for method APIService.savePost`

Here is my Interface code:

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("fetchtext.php")
    Call<List<DataStored>> savePost(@Field("catId") String catId);
    @GET("testing.php")
    Call<List<DataStored>> searchcategory(@Field("catId") String catId,
            @Field("SubCatego") String SubCatego);
}
```

Here is my ApiUtils Class:

```
    public class ApiUtils {

  private ApiUtils() {}

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.9.10/";

    public static APIService getAPIService() {

        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

RetrofitClient Class:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }}
```

Code In Fragment where I am creating calling RetroApi:

```
 mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
     mAPIService.savePost(category).enqueue(new Callback<List<DataStored>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<DataStored>> call, Response<List<DataStored>> response) {
                dataStored=  response.body();
                myRecyclerAdapter.addItems(dataStored);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<DataStored>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Please tell me how can I send category to database to compare if that
   category data available in database then data convert into Json and send  back in android to show on RecyclerView in android.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET("fetchtext.php")
Call<List<DataStored>> savePost(@Field("catId") String catId);
```

@Field is used to send POST data. To fetch data you should use @Query

```
@GET("fetchtext.php")
Call<List<DataStored>> savePost(@Query("catId") String catId);
```

Comment: now getting this error....... Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: You are getting a malformed json, It's hard to say what is wrong without seen it.

Comment: now getting  this error....Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Retrofit is expecting a List<DataStored> but its receiving a string. You json should be something like [{"field1":"value"},{"field1":"value"},{"field1":"value"}] so gson can parse it.